# Adding File Server to Trusted Sites through REG ADD Command

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, batch

I'm trying to add a trusted site to a group of Win 7 computers that need to run batch files without security prompts.

Adding the file server to trusted sites allows them to run.  I don't want to manually add the site to 100 computers so I'd like to script it with "REG ADD" but it's not working.  MY syntax is as follows:

Hostname of FS is "Our-File-Server"

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\Our-File-Server" /v "file" /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /Y
```

This returns `Invalid Syntax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per `reg add /?`, there is no `/Y` option. To force overwriting the existing registry entry without prompt, use `/f` instead.

Truly, I don't *know* whether this setting will allow running batch scripts without security prompts. I'd add that option *manually* and prove its functionality first (on any machine) and then check appropriate registry changes as follows:

```
REG query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\Our-File-Server"
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I already tested it manually.